# CMake: a "find_package(Boost)" works great, but another not

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm constructing Boost Asio's [timer example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer1/src.html) for cross-platform. So I used CMake to automate build system.

**File structure:**

```
- timer
  - build (Just empty)
  - dep
    - boost
      - boost
      - doc
      - libs
      - ...
      - CMakeLists.txt (Important)
      - ...
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - src
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - timer.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
```

Other CMake scripts except `dep/boost/CMakeLists.txt` are just include some scripts in subdirectories or configure the project, that is all!

**dep/boost/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
# Boost settings
set(BOOST_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS     ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED   ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME  ON)

# Specify Boost libraries that will use.
set(boost_components system date_time regex)
set(boost_components_option --with-system --with-date_time --with-regex)

# Find compiled Boost
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ${boost_components}) <-- STMT1
# If couldn't find it, compile Boost before process.
if(NOT ${Boost_FOUND})
  if(WIN32)
    set(bootstrap_name bootstrap.bat)
    set(bootstrap_command bootstrap.bat)
    set(b2_name b2.exe)
    set(b2_command b2.exe)
    set(b2_variant debug,release)
  else()
    set(bootstrap_name bootstrap.sh)
    set(bootstrap_command ./bootstrap.sh)
    set(b2_name b2)
    set(b2_command ./b2)
    set(b2_variant release)
  endif()
  if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${bootstrap_name})
    if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${b2_name})
      if(UNIX)
        execute_process(COMMAND chmod +x
        ${bootstrap_name} tools/build/src/engine/build.sh
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
      endif()
      execute_process(COMMAND ${bootstrap_command}
                      WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
    endif()
  else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could NOT find ${bootstrap_name}")
  endif()
  if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${b2_name})
    execute_process(COMMAND ${b2_command} ${boost_components_option}
                    variant=${b2_variant} link=static threading=multi
                    runtime-link=static
                    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
  else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could NOT find ${b2_name}")
  endif()
  # After compile Boost, re-find it.
  find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${boost_components}) <-- STMT2
endif()
```

Okay... When I commanded `cmake ..` in `build` directory on console, it works greatly on Windows 10, but an issue occurs on Ubuntu 14.04. The issue is that CMake could NOT find Boost libraries despite after compiling it(Boost libraries, at STMT2). That's not all. Curiously, CMake find it without any problems if just command `cmake ..` in `build` directory (exactly same, at STMT1). Understandably, all required Boost libraries are compiled in `dep/boost/stage/lib` directory before the issue occured. And apparently, `STMT1` and `STMT2` are exactly same except `REQUIRED` is specified or not. I checked some variables related with Boost and re-declared it with proper values, but it couldn't help me.

**First command console output:**

```
user@user-pc:~/desktop/timer/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Could NOT find Boost
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset gcc... tools/build/src/engine/bin.linuxx86_64/b2
Detecting Python version... 2.7
Detecting Python root... /usr
Unicode/ICU support for Boost.Regex?... not found.
Generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam...

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:

    ./b2

To adjust configuration, edit 'project-config.jam'.
Further information:

   - Command line help:
     ./b2 --help

   - Getting started guide: 
     http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

   - Boost.Build documentation:
     http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/index.html

Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : no
    - 64-bit                   : yes
    - arm                      : no
    - mips1                    : no
    - power                    : no
    - sparc                    : no
    - x86                      : yes

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


    - has_icu builds           : no

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : not building
    - chrono                   : not building
    - container                : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - coroutine                : not building
    - date_time                : building
    - exception                : not building
    - filesystem               : not building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - locale                   : not building
    - log                      : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : building
    - serialization            : not building
    - signals                  : not building
    - system                   : building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - timer                    : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...patience...
...found 1092 targets...
...updating 51 targets...
common.mkdir stage
common.mkdir stage/lib
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.8
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.8/release
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/gregorian
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_weekday.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/gregorian/date_generators.o
gcc.archive bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/libboost_date_time.a
common.copy stage/lib/libboost_date_time.a
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/c_regex_traits.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/cpp_regex_traits.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/cregex.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/fileiter.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/icu.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/instances.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/posix_api.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/regex.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/regex_debug.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/regex_raw_buffer.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/regex_traits_defaults.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/static_mutex.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/w32_regex_traits.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/wc_regex_traits.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/wide_posix_api.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/winstances.o
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/usinstances.o
gcc.archive bin.v2/libs/regex/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/libboost_regex.a
common.copy stage/lib/libboost_regex.a
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/system
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/system/build
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/error_code.o
gcc.archive bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/libboost_system.a
common.copy stage/lib/libboost_system.a
...updated 51 targets...


The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    /home/user/desktop/timer/dep/boost

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    /home/user/desktop/timer/dep/boost/stage/lib

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1131 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.58.0

  Boost include path: /home/user/desktop/timer/dep/boost

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_date_time
          boost_regex

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  dep/boost/CMakeLists.txt:50 (find_package)
  dep/CMakeLists.txt:2 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/desktop/timer/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

**Second command console output:**

```
user@user-pc:~/desktop/timer/build$ cmake ..
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   date_time
--   regex
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/desktop/timer/build
```

What is going on exactly? And how to solve it? Thanks.